# Immersion is equivalent to local embedding: Different proof when image is submanifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, differential-topology

**Update**: Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714579/bijective-immersion-is-a-diffeomorphism), I think: **Surjective immersions are local diffeomorphisms** because surjective immersions have $\dim {\text{domain}} = \dim{\text{range/image}}$. Similarly, **immersions whose images are (regular/embedded) submanifolds of range are local diffeomorphisms onto their images** because $\dim {\text{domain}} = \dim{\text{image}}$, i.e. $n=k$, as below. Please verify that this in fact answers these three questions:

1. [Immersions whose images are actually submanifolds? Or surjective immersions? (I think surjective immersions are local diffeomorphisms)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301261/what-can-we-say-about-immersions-whose-images-are-actually-submanifolds-or-surj)
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301259/are-immersions-equivalent-to-local-diffeomorphisms-onto-their-images-if-their-im
3. [Immersion is equivalent to local embedding: Different proof when image is submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301159/immersion-and-local-embedding)

---

**Question A**. For these proofs (one on [stackexchange,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059110/every-immersion-is-locally-an-embedding) one on [wordpress](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/immersions-are-locally-embeddings/)) that immersions are local embeddings:

- I understand that images of immersions are [immersed submanifolds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCxS5.png), not necessarily (regular/embedded) submanifolds and not necessarily manifolds.
- Do I understand correctly that, nevertheless, immersions are local embeddings and that these proofs indeed prove such with the images of the immersions being assumed only immersed submanifolds?

**Question B**. Is this proof for immersion, whose image is a submanifold, is a local embedding correct? (I won't prove that local embeddings are immersions.)

- In particular, I'm not sure about (5). I think (5) is true if $F(N)$ has the same dimension as $N$. I think I at least proved local diffeomorphisms onto images with images submanifolds are local embeddings

1. Let $N$ and $M$ be smooth manifolds with respective dimensions $n$ and $m$. Let $p \in N$. Let $F: N \to M$ be an immersion at $p$. Let its image $F(N)$ be a (regular/embedded) $k$-submanifold of $M$.
2. Let us show $F$ is a local embedding at $p$, defined as that there exists a neighborhood $V_p$ of $p$ in $N$ such that $F|_{V_p}: V_p \to M$ is an embedding.
3. Because $F(N)$ is a submanifold of $M$, $F(N)$ is a manifold, so it would make sense to say, if we were to say that

- 3.1. The inclusion $\iota: F(N) \to M$ is a map of manifolds
- 3.2. $\tilde F: N \to F(N)$, $F$ with restricted range that satisfies $F = \iota \circ \tilde F$, is a map of manifolds.

4. Assert (3.1) and (3.2). Additionally, the maps in (3) are smooth because $F(N)$ is a submanifold:

- 4.1. $\iota$ is smooth by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299400/submanifold-implies-inclusion-is-embedding-why-is-the-inclusion-smooth-in-the-f)
- 4.2. $\tilde F$ is smooth by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wn3q.png).

5. $\tilde F$ is a local diffeomorphism, i.e. $F$ is a ["local diffeomorphism onto its image"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298630/what-is-the-definition-of-local-diffeomorphism-homeomorphism-onto-image) by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301259/are-immersions-equivalent-to-local-diffeomorphisms-onto-their-images-if-their-im), where there is no ambiguity in the definition of ["local diffeomorphism onto its image"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298630/what-is-the-definition-of-local-diffeomorphism-homeomorphism-onto-image) because its image is a submanifold.

- **Edit: Not quite sure about this step actually. I think true if $n=k$.**

6. Let $G=\tilde F$ By (5), there exists a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ in $N$ such that $G(U_p)$ is open in $F(N)$, and $\tilde{G|_{U_p}}: U_p \to G(U_p)$ is a diffeomorphism, where $\tilde{G|_{U_p}}$ is $G|_{U_p}: U_p \to F(N)$ with restricted range.
7. Choose $V_p = U_p$. This works because, under [this definition for embedding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCxS5.png), [equivalent to the more natural one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297560/equivalent-definitions-for-smooth-embedding):

- 7.1 $G|_{U_p}$ is an immersion if and only if $\tilde{G|_{U_p}}$ is an immersion, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299401/tilde-f-immersion-is-equivalent-to-f-immersion).
- 7.2 $G|_{U_p}$ is a topological embedding because $\tilde{G|_{U_p}}$ is a homeomorphism because $\tilde{G|_{U_p}}$ is a diffeomorphism.
- 7.3 $F|_{U_p} = \iota \circ G|_{U_p}$
- 7.4 $F|_{U_p}$ is an immersion if both $G|_{U_p}$ and $\iota$ are immersions.
- 7.5 $\iota$ is an immersion by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcju.png).
- 7.6 $\tilde{G|_{U_p}}$ is an immersion since $\tilde{G|_{U_p}}$ is a diffeomorphism.
- 7.7 $G|_{U_p}$ is an immersion by (7.1) and (7.6).
- 7.8 Therefore, $F|_{U_p}$ is an immersion by (7.4) and (7.7).
- 7.9 $F|_{U_p}$ is a topological embedding if and only if $G|_{U_p}$ is a topoloigcal embedding.
- 7.10 Therefore, $F|_{U_p}$ is a topological embedding by (7.9) and (7.2).
- 7.11 Therefore, $F|_{U_p}$ is a smooth embedding by (7.10) and (7.8).